# having trouble inflating view in custom expandable list adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I created a custom expandable list adapter and inside the getGroupView()
and getChildView() i do the following but recieve an error:

```
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_parent_row_layout);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

compiler tells me that it cannot find method - getActivity()

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the adapter constructor, you will have a Context argument. Use this (Activity)context to getLayoutInflater.

Adapter class does not have getActivity() method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to post more of your code - I suspect your accessing this in an Activity and not a Fragment (which provides the method, getActivity())

You need your Context in the code, this is what your code should look like.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```